# How should I structure my table and foreign keys?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am a noob when it comes to foreign keys so please point me to any good/descriptive learning resources that may be helpful. Let's say I am trying to build a basic user/role system. I have two tables:

```
user_role : id, role
user: id, role_id, name
```

How and what type of foreign key constraint should I use in both tables? I want it so that A role that is assigned to even one user cannot be deleted till the user is moved to another role.

I am using phpMyadmin, so if you can give directions for it, that would be most appreciated.

Comment: In your proposed schema a user could belong to one and only one role at any given time. Is that what you intend? Also, it's fairly common for roles to be hierarchical in nature (e.g. "Employee", "Manager", "Executive").

Comment: Yes, one user can only have one role. Also roles are supposed to be separate in my system, but just out of curiosity, how would I implement a hierarchical model like that? simply link them with role_parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple query for adding a foreign key constraint to your user table would be as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE `user` 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_User_Role 
FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`) 
REFERENCES `user_role` (`id`)
```

That would accomplish what you are setting out to do.